# arrayListOf and hashMapOf: Unresolved reference

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to play with the Kotlin [HTML builder example](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Longer%20examples/HTML%20Builder/HTML%20Builder.kt) on my local machine.

In

```
abstract class Tag(val name: String) : Element {
    val children = arrayListOf<Element>()
    val attributes = hashMapOf<String, String>()
```

IntelliJ idea rants about `arrayListOf` and `hashMapOf` being unresolved.

[image: Screenshot]

Importing `kotlin.collections` (`import kotlin.collections.*`), where [arrayListOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html) is defined, didn't help.

How can I fix those errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you use the latest 1.0 kotlin plugin and 1.0 runtime. After that invalidating IJ caches and restarting IJ might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

### I did the following-

##### Step 1: Make sure your internet is active during the process.

##### Step 2: Go to Tools>Kotlin>Configure Kotlin Plugin Update. Click "CHECK AGAIN" and install the latest version. After Install, Restart IDE.

##### Step 3: Go to Tools>Kotlin>Configure Kotlin In Project. Alternatively, Open Project level build.gradle and in dependency, make the classpath version, **"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:x.xx.xx"** same as the plugin version.

##### Step 4: Click Builde>Rebuild. IDE will download the necessary kotlin tools. After done, Restart.

##### Step 5: Go to Help>Check for updates. Update IDE to latest version. After Download, click Restart. Skip if already done.

##### Step 6: Go to File>Invalidate caches/Restart and click "Invalidate and Restart". After restart, don't panic if you see a lot of errors in kt files. Just make sure you have the Internet and let IDE do it's work. After complete, just wait a little and all the errors will be gone.